# How to Validate an array size

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have one parameter called tags I am getting that parameter in tags[1,2,3,4,5] format now I need to validate that thing to only 4 values allow in tags parameter.

How can i do that ?

I tried various methods but not succeed.

```
$rules = array(
    'ids'  => 'required',
    'note' => 'required|array|min:3',
    'tags' => 'required|array|max:4',           
);
```

I am not able validating that thing properly.

I am not even allow 4 parameters to be entered.

Comment: 'products.1.quantity' => 'required|numeric|min:1', try like this

Answer (score 1):

```php
public function rules()
    {
        $limit = 3;

        return [
            'notas' => 'required|array|size:'.$limit
        ];
    }

public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'notas.required' => 'O valor de Notas é obrigatório.',
            'notas.array' => 'O valor de Notas deve ser um array.',
            'notas.size' => 'Aquantidade de notas não pode ser maior que :size'
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom validation rule (e.g. `ValidateArraySize`) and declare it in your service provider. Use the validation rule like this `array_size:4`

```
/**
 * Validate the size of an array.
 *
 * @param mixed $attribute
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param array $parameters
 */ 
public function validateArraySize($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $data = array_get($this->data, $attribute);

    if(!is_array($data)){
        return true;
    }

    $validateSize = count($data) <= $parameters[0];

    return $validateSize;
}
```

Comment: In which file I need to create that function ?

Comment: I put that function in validator.php in Illuminate\Validation